# Javascript change background color with function and css of a list item

Tags: javascript, html, css, list, button

i have a function with the following segment as seen below and what i want to do is to modify the background color of a list item when people click the edit button that is inside the list. Somehow i don't get is to work. So the idea is to use the unique id for each list item of the group and use that one as an unique id in the second function, what am i doing wrong.

```
function datafromJSON(id_program) {
$.ajax({
    url: "/xxxxxx",
    type: "GET",
    success: function (data) {

        $.each(data, function (i, item) {

     var li = '<li id='ihaveaname ' + dataidfromdb + '" style =background-color:transparent;" > '
           + ' < a href = "" id = "clickonme" > < span class = "icon-edit" < /span></a > '
           + ' < /li>';

         $('#clickonme').click(function () {
           $('#ihaveaname' + dataidfromdb  + '').css("background-color", "red");
         });

      });
   });
}
```

Comment: I have ran tidy on your code, and it should now be obvious why this problem occurs. You quotes do not seem to match.

Comment: You appear to be appear to be creating an `html` string which would append duplicate `id`'s to `document`; though string is not actually appended to `document`. Also, `data`, `ihaveaname`, `dataidfromdb` do not appear to be defined within `datafromdbwithJSON` function?

Comment: hi, yes is stripped down the first function of the code so be more able to demonstrate what i want to do, however that part works perfect. It's about the second part, the clickonme function i can't seem to work..

Comment: Try moving `.click()` outside of `$.each()`

Comment: nope did not work as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer i found, for the people that interest it. Since it is a list and the items get repeated the ID's get repeated as well and you're not allowed to use the same id twice. So by renaming the id to a unique name as well (in this case i added also the dataid to that one the function works perfect. Now i am able to use various css effects on the list elements or any other div therefor on the page.

```
function datafromJSON(id_program) {
$.ajax({
url: "/xxxxxx",
type: "GET",
success: function (data) {

    $.each(data, function (i, item) {

 var li = '<li id='ihaveaname ' + dataidfromdb + '" style =background-color:transparent;" > '
       + ' < a href = "" id = "clickonme ' + dataidfromdb + '" > < span class = "icon-edit" < /span></a > '
       + ' < /li>';

     $('#clickonme' + dataidfromdb +').click(function () {
       $('#ihaveaname' + dataidfromdb  + '').css("background-color", "red");
     });

  });
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in general it's not good idea to create click handler on each anchor, instead you can use bubbling of events to parent, and you should add to achor class .edit-parent for filtering of edit events...

```
$('ul.parentofli').on('click', '.edit-parent', function(event) {
  $(event.target).closest('li').css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

Comment: hi, my friend was thinking in the same direction but i don't know how to implement this what you wrote on code.

Comment: Hi Ewald, i don't know how to help you more. You have posted only example of code. I quess you have somewhere <ul> element where you append dynamic <li> elements, when you recive JSON from server. So remove  $('#clickonme') handler from your example code and add my handler to your <ul> element (even before you create ajax request) and to each dynamic <a> add edit-parent class.